# Qt QML anchor not working in custom Item

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm new of qml.
I'm starting to develop a little application with a custom item.
when I try to use in application `anchor.top: first_item.bottom`, to position the rectangles of the custom component, one below the other doesn't work.

content file main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Item
{
    id:main_screen
    Rectangle
    {
        width: 300
        height: 60

        id: text_content
        color: "DarkGray"
        opacity: 0.9
        border.color: "blue"
        border.width: 3
        radius: 5
        z:6

        Text {
            id: titleText
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            font.pointSize: 20
            font.family: "Arial"
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            text: "Test - title"
            color: "White"; style: Text.Raised;
        }
    }


//..................This rectangle is shown below main_screen... so is OK
    Custom_item
    {
        id:first_item
        anchors.top: main_screen.bottom
    }

//..................This rectangle is not shown below first_item... but it shown on absolute top, in overlap of  retangle title
    Custom_item
    {
        id:second_item
        anchors.top: first_item.bottom
    }

//..................This rectangle is not shown below second_item... but it shown on absolute top, in overlap of  retangle title
    Custom_item
    {
        id:third_item
        anchors.top: second_item.bottom
    }
}
```

content file Custom_item.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Item
{
    id:testComponent

    Rectangle
    {
        width: 300
        height: 60

        id: text_content

        color: "DarkGray"
        opacity: 0.9
        border.color: "blue"
        border.width: 3
        radius: 5
        z:6
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend also posting a screenshot, instead of trying to explain the ui problem, i.e instead of "This rectangle is not shown below first_item... but it shown on absolute top, in overlap of rectangle title" a screenshot would save a thousand words :)

Comment: It features a mcve, which explains the problem than thousand pictures. A commendable first post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies within the dimensions of the objects your are anchoring to.

Though the `Rectangle`s have a `width` and a `height`, the enclosing `Item` has none, so it is basically 0 pixels in height and width, while the `Rectangle` protrudes it.

If you don't have any reason for enclosing the `Rectangle` within the `Item`, I'd reccomend you, to take the `Rectangle` itself as the toplevel element of the file.

Reasons for having the `Item` might be those:

- Hiding the `Rectangles` properties
- Having multiple children for the `Item` that are logically siblings to the `Rectangle`
- ... other reasons might exist ;-)

Nevertheless, you need to make sure, that the toplevel item has always the right dimensions. So you should set the width and height, better the [`implicitWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitWidth-prop) and [`implicitHeight`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitHeight-prop) in component declarations.

Example 1: Without an `Item`

```
import QtQuick 2.5
Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 300
    height: 60

    color: "DarkGray"
    opacity: 0.9
    border.color: "blue"
    border.width: 3
    radius: 5
    z:6
}
```

Example 2: With `Item`

```
import QtQuick 2.5
Item {
    id:testComponent
    implicitHeight: 60  // < This
    implicitWidth: 300  // < and that are important to have the dimensions

    Rectangle {
        id: text_content

        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "DarkGray"
        opacity: 0.9
        border.color: "blue"
        border.width: 3
        radius: 5
        z:6
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying ideas!

Answer (score -1):

You are anchoring all the `Rectangle`'s to the `Item` hence you are not getting the desired result. Simple change the id of the top `Rectangle` as follows

```
Item
{
    id: root        
    Rectangle
    {
        id:main_screen
        ...
    }
}
```